# Why is high-gain controller undesirable?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, adaptive-control

In control theory and for example the scalar plant:

$\dot{x}=ax+u+d$

where $x$ is the state and $u$ is input and $d$ is disturbance

If the following control law is chosen:

$u=-kx$

where

$k\geq |a|$ and $|d|\geq d_0$

Then the steady-state value for $x$ is bounded as following:

$|x|\leq\dfrac{d_0}{k-a}$

by increasing the value of $k$ we can make the steady-state value of $x$ as small as we like. But this leads to high-gain controller which is undesirable.

My question is Why the high-gain controller is undesirable in this case and in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of different practical reasons:

- In reality, you can't make $u$ infinitly large, so $k \rightarrow \infty$ which would make $|x| \rightarrow 0$ is not feasible.
- In reality, you also have measurement noise which gets also amplified by large $k$.
- Also, in reality, large $u$ come with a cost (like energy consumption) so large $k$ can be too expensive.

But there are more problems with high gain. In many cases you dont really have a continous controller like in your system, but a digital. For the continous scalar system:

$$
\dot{x} = a x + u \tag{1}
$$

and $u = -k x$ with $k > |a|$ you have $a - k < 0$ so the system is stable, no matter how large you take $k$ as long as its larger than $|a|$.

But if you have a digital controller, you end up with a discrete system. For example $(1)$ has the transfer function

$$
G(s) = \frac{1}{s - a}
$$

which is discretized with sample-and-hold element and sample time $T$:

$$
G(z) = \frac{e^{a T} - 1}{a(z - e^{a T})}
$$

Closed loop with static state feedback and gain $k$:

$$
G_c(z) = \frac{1 - e^{a T}}{k + a e^{a T} - a z - k e^{a T}}
$$

This transfer function has the pole

$$
\frac{k(1 - e^{a T})}{a} + e^{a T}
$$

that is outside the unit circle for large $k$. So high gain feedback can make your system unstable even if the continous system is stable, because of discretization.

Comment: Another reason would be time delays, which most digital controllers have due to the computation time of the ADC, control signal computation and DAC (one could also argue that the zero order hold discretization method effectively adds half a time sample of delay).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Good point, even the smallest non-zero time delay prevents arbitrary high $k$ because it lets the phase drop towards $-\infty$ for high frequencies. And in reality, there is pretty much always some kind of time delay.

Comment: This can then also be generalized to any non-minimum phase system, which for LTI systems means RHP zeros. The limits of high gain feedback can then also been seen from root locus, in which the closedloop poles go to the (openloop) zeros as the gain goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

High gain controllers is general are undesirable because of considerations of robustness - sensitivity to noise and unmodeled dynamics.

The most effective way to understand those considerations is to study classical, frequency domain linear control - the names Bode, Nyquist, and Evans will show up. Trying to understand nonlinear control theory in the time domain without going through classical control before is flying blind.

Comment: Could you please explain with more details the relation between high-gain controller and high-frequency unmodeled dynamic?